# Create a route to display entries with multiple tags

Tags: tags, routes

I understand how to set up a route and template that allows me to display entries by tag.

But how can I set up a template + route to grab multiple tags (if supplied but could just be one) from the url and display entires that have these tags?

I would also like to add a category element (showing all the entires from a category with the selected tags) but suspect much of that may be answered by the first part.

For example

Have a form the builds a url depending on user selections

mysite/queryurl&tags=cheese,egg,bacon&cat=sandwich

Is this possible?

Comment: I have just discovered `{% set query = craft.request.getParam('tags') %}` on the search example page. I will investigate this.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you're using commas to separate the tag names in the URL:

```
mysite.com?queryurl&tags=cheese,egg,bacon&cat=sandwich
```

then you should be able to retrieve the multiple tags like so:

```
{% set tagsString = craft.request.getParam('tags') %}

{% set tags = craft.tags.name(tagsString).find() %}

<ul>
    {% for tag in tags %}
        <li>{{ tag.name }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
{/ul>
```

Comment: So I shouldn't be creating a route at all - I should be using the search instead?
Small typo on the closing `</ul>` element.

Comment: This code seems to work without the code above being required to set "tags"?
`<ul>
    {% for tag in tags %}
        <li>{{ tag.name }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
{/ul>`

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I think I worked this out (with a little help from Brad and the search example page). Though there might be a better way of achieving the same result.

```
    <ul>Looking for:
    {% for tag in tags %}
        <li>{{ tag.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

The code above demonstrates that Craft pulls the tags from the URL into the an array called "tags" automatically(?). For each entry I loop through these tags - for each one loop through the entries tags to see if they match. I set matchFound to false before starting and at the end of each entry. If I hit a matching tag I set it to true to remove entries being listed multiple times.

```
{% for tag in tags %}

        {% for thisItemTag in entry.tags %}

                {% set lookingFor = tag.name %}
                {% set currentTag = thisItemTag %}

                <!-- <li>{{ thisItemTag }}</li> -->
                {% if lookingFor == currentTag %}
                    {% if matchFound == false %}
                        {% set matchFound = true %}
                        <article class="product">
                            <h3>{{ entry.title }}</h3>
                        </article>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}
    {% set matchFound = false %}
```